# Example question about the exponential distribution

Tags: self-study, exponential-family

I was given the following question. My answer C was marked incorrect.
[image: Quiz 6.2.]

My method of calculating it was to use the exponential distribution with the parameter $\lambda = 2$: $$\int_{0.75}^\infty 2e^{-2x} \text {d} x = \left. \lim_{n \to \infty} -e^{-2x}\right]_{0.75}^n = 0+ e^{-2 \times 0.75} \approx 0.22 $$

What did I do incorrectly?

Comment: Hint: the mean of an exponential is $1/\lambda$, not $\lambda$.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: @gung Thank you for the suggestion. I did search for a `[homework]` tag, but I didn't find one, and I wouldn't have expected `[self-study]` to include questions that come from a university course anyway. It seems that your comment is rather generic, as I have actually explained my working sufficiently. You come across patronizing because you are not clear about how I could have asked my question differently - either that, or you haven't actually read my question. Next time, have a look at a new user's credentials on other SE sites. In any case, I have realized where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the wrong parameterization. When the mean of the Exponential distribution is $\beta = 2$,

$$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{\beta}e^{-x/\beta}. $$

Comment: Oh, it's not the first time I've made that mistake. I'm still pretty new to the exponential distribution.